ようとする in passive constructions

あなたが入らされようとしてるのはそこの涼宮がこれから作る活動内容未定で名称不明の同好会ですよ

I'm not 100% sure what does this ようとする do here.
If I reconsturct it into an active sentence:

涼宮があなたを入らそうとしてるのは.....

But then the とする is distributed towards the 涼宮, whereas in the passive sentence it's distributed towards the あなた, or is it not?
With that in mind, it feels as if the とする in the passive sentence is closer to:

ちょうど…しようとする

While in the active sentence it's

試みたり、遂行の意志を表したりするさま

What do I make out of this?

volitional-form + とする means "to try to ～" or "to attempt to ～", but volitional-form + としている also means "to be about to ～" or "to be on the verge of ～ing". See: 【JLPT N２】文法・例文：〜ようとしている
入らされよう is the causative-passive-volitional form, as shown below.

入る
to enter
入らせる
to make someone enter
入らされる
to be made to enter
入らされようとしている
to be about to be made to enter
あなたが入らされようとしてるのは...
The thing you're about to be made to enter is...
あなたが入らされようとしてるのはそこの涼宮がこれから作る活動内容未定で名称不明の同好会ですよ。
The club you're about to be dragged into is an unnamed club with unspecified activities that Suzumiya over there is going to create.

